# Как преобразовать строку String в массив?

Tags: java, android

Есть строка:

```
13;;;256;592;1200;2320;4632;5140;2066;1009;594;4688;4688;
```

Как по-простому ее преобразовать в массив:

```
ar[0]=13
ar[1]=0
ar[2]=0
ar[3]=256
ar[4]=592
```

и т.д.

---

Я сделал так:

```
String text = "13;;;256;592;1200;2320;4632;5140;2066;1009;594;4688;4688";
String ar[] = text.split(";");
```

Получилось:

```
ar[0]=13
ar[1]=
ar[2]=
ar[3]=256
ar[4]=592
```

и т.д.

Comment: public String[] split(String regex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    String text = "13;;;256;592;1200;2320;4632;5140;2066;1009;594;4688;4688";
    String[] numbers = text.split(";");
    ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String x : numbers) {
        if (x.equals("")){ar.add(0);}
        else ar.add(Integer.parseInt(x));
    }
```

Comment: Ваш ответ самый полный. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Если разделитель ,только, скобка с запятой-тогда так.

```
mString.split(";")
```

Comment: Да, это самый быстрый способ оказался. Благодарю.